# Lambda expression inside Kotlin String

Tags: kotlin

My code:

```
class Team (val name: String, val aggressive: Boolean = true) {

    val attendance: Int

    init {
        if (aggressive){
            attendance = 25000
        } else {
            attendance = 20000
        }
    }

}
```

...

```
fun chooseTeam() {
    val homeTeam = Team(name = "Everton")
    println("the home team is $homeTeam.aggressive so they are ${if ($homeTeam == "aggressive") "angry" else "timid" }") 
}
```

I'm trying to assign the value of the lambda string based on if `$homeTeam.aggressive` is true or not.

However I'm getting red lines all over the lambda so obviously the syntax seems off. Can someone tell me whats wrong with the code?

Comment: It is string template not lambda string

Comment: Add the whole `class`.

Comment: Added whole class @Zlytherin

Comment: the variable defined is aggressive but you are using aggression

Comment: I've updated all my code now

Comment: Ok, let me check

Comment: Solved. Problem was putting `$` before `homeTeam` in the if lambda

Comment: I think you wanted to put the name (homeTeam.name) in the string and then the adjective, which has to be determined by homeTeam.aggression == true not by homeTeam == true (which does not work). see my answer. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The correct way

```sh
fun chooseTeam() {
    val homeTeam = Team(name = "Everton")

    // 1) no dollar sign before homeTeam in the comparison 
    // 2) in kotlin if you declare constructor parameter as val they also becomes property of class which you can access like this homeTeam.aggressive
    // 2) if you want the name of team, just use ${homeTeam.name} instead $homeTeam.aggression
    println("the home team is $homeTeam.aggression so they are ${if(homeTeam.aggressive) "angry" else "timid"}") 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Edit :
More detailed explanation is given by @Willi Mentzel

Comment: and if `homeTeam.aggression` is an expected value, try `${homeTeam.aggression}` in former.

Comment: Since the lines are as long as they are similar, it would be helpful to mention that you just removed the `$` before `home.aggressive` inside the `${…}` expression.

Answer (score 5):

What you actually mean is a [string template](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#string-templates) and not a lambda. You must have confused it because both use curly brackets `{...}`.

You can either do it like this:

```
fun chooseTeam() {
    val homeTeam = Team(name = "Everton")

    // 1) no dollar sign before homeTeam in the comparison
    // 2) you need to compare to homeTeam.aggressive and not homeTeam
    println("the home team is ${homeTeam.name} so they are ${if (homeTeam.aggressive) "angry" else "timid" }")
}
```

Or better, you assign the mapping (`Boolean` to `String`) to a variable first which increases the readability.

```
fun chooseTeam() {
    val homeTeam = Team(name = "Everton")
    val adjective = if (homeTeam.aggressive) "angry" else "timid"

    println("the home team is ${homeTeam.name} so they are $adjective")
}
```

Comment: Thanks the 2nd option is much cleaner.